# Is there any way to mock field of Class

Tags: mockito

Here's my case, I have a class A which has one member field b. And I want to test and in unit test, I mocked A and also need to call method f() which will invoke b's f(). But the b variable in mocked A is null, so will throw NPE, and I have no get/set method for b, so is there any way to mock b ? THanks

```
public static class B{
    public void f() {

    }
  }

  public static class A {
    B b;

    public void f() {
      b.f();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to mock A? From your description you want to test `A.f`- then mocking B would be appropriate - like in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mock out the `b` property of A in a test, you've given the `b` property default (package-private) access, so as long as your test is in the same package you could replace the b property directly.

```
@Test
public void testB() {
    A underTest = new A();
    B mockedB = Mockito.mock(B.class);
    underTest.b = mockedB;

    underTest.f();

    Mockito.verify(mockedB).f();
}
```

As an aside, I personally dislike using package-private access to mess around with member properties for tests, and instead would recommend a dependency injection framework like [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice) or [Spring DI](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) for constructor injection.

However you've described that you've mocked out A, I'd have thought if this was the case the f() method of A would do nothing - you wouldn't get a null pointer exception as the call to the mock will replace the real b property and just be a void method that does nothing. Please can you provide more details if this is the case?

Comment: Mockito can inject mocks into private fields. (look at examples with `@MockitoJunitRunner`, `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks`). I would discourage using depency injection for such things, Mockito is more consise, faster and has less side effects.

Comment: Ah I should clarify, I mean that I'd prefer to write my main codebase using DI with constructor injection, to allow me to write unit tests easily using the constructor (not using the DI framework), something like `A underTest = new A(mock1, mock2);`, whereas I'd prefer to avoid private fields set by Mockito.